# Parallel time is sequential space

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, parallel-computing, space-complexity

Studying for my qualifying exam, have a past exam here, which has the following question, verbatim:

> Give a proof of the Folklore statement: "sequential space is parallel time." In other words, the space used by a sequential algorithm for a problem $X$ can be equated (within Big Oh) to the time taken by a parallel algorithm for $X$.

However, in the textbook I have, I haven't found a good definition for a sequential algorithm or parallel algorithm, which is necessary if I'm going to prove anything.  Also, googling turned up the wikipedia page  on [parallel computation thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computation_thesis)
but it seems to depend on the model of computation used.  So I'm not sure how to answer this question.

Comment: I agree: this question is ill-posed without context, and does not admit an answer. It seems clear this this is a question about complexities of problems, not cost of algorithms.